# How can I keep my application in the foreground?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

**Question:** How do I keep my application in the foreground and/or prevent it from going to the background ever?

I have created an application and managed to get it to automatically start when the device has booted. The purpose of the app is to show some data and never ever go to the menu or terminate unless I want it too.

Every now and then the ActivityManager decides that my app is not important enough and wants to send it to the background or even worse, kill it entirely. Sometimes it happens after 1, 4 or 16 hours.

**So far** I have found out how to check if the app receives various ApplicationEvents with:

```
function TForm1.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  case AAppEvent of
    TApplicationEvent.FinishedLaunching: MemoPrint('Finished Launching');
    TApplicationEvent.BecameActive: MemoPrint('Became Active');
    TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeInactive: MemoPrint('Will Become Inactive');
    TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground: MemoPrint('Entered Background');
    TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground: MemoPrint('Will Become Foreground');
    TApplicationEvent.WillTerminate: MemoPrint('Will Terminate');
    TApplicationEvent.LowMemory: MemoPrint('Low Memory');
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.LinkAppEvent;
var
  aFMXApplicationEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService,
    IInterface(aFMXApplicationEventService)) then
    aFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent)
  else
    MemoPrint('Application Event Service is not supported.');
end;
```

So I would like to know how to proceed from here. Hopefully I was on the right track so far. :)

Comment: I dont think you can keep it in foreground. If you wants to perform some task repeatedly you can use a Service which will keep on running in background even if the app is not in use

Comment: The application refreshes it's data every xx seconds or minute to display fresh data. But it is important that it is also (always) shown and not just available in the background.

Maybe the TApplicationEvent is not the right way to go, maybe there are other options to keep my app active...

Comment: What you can do is run a Service in the background and when new data is available you can show the notification to the user and when user clicks on the notification the required data is displayed. Like all the news and other apps are doing.

Comment: And when this information should be available without interaction, could I for example let my app react on this notification and like that keep the app 'active', would that work?

I hope there are more options as I also do not want to have a notification showing that there is new data.

Comment: You can have a Handler which pings your server for new data at particular intervals. But even in that case you wont be able to bring your app to the foreground until or unless user performs some action with your app.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess that's as good as it's going to get then.

Comment: Yupz I dont think there is any other option available... Still I would recommend using a Service. Should I post that as an answer if you gonna Accept it please?

Comment: @ShivamDev, yes please. I waited a bit in the hope for additional information but since this is the only way I guess I will really have to do it like this.

Comment: I have posted that as an answer. you can accept that as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can keep it in foreground. If you wants to perform some task repeatedly you can use a Service which will keep on running in background even if the app is not in use.

What you can do is run a Service in the background and when new data is available you can show the notification to the user and when user clicks on the notification the required data is displayed. Like all the news and other apps are doing.

Plus, you can have a Handler which pings your server for new data at particular intervals. But even in that case you wont be able to bring your app to the foreground until or unless user performs some action with your app.